# How to make column chart start animation with Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts

I'm using Google Charts. It has an animation function but this one is not working for me. The documentation says that you have to add something like this:

```
    animation: {
       startup:true,
       duration: 2000,
       easing: 'in',
    },
```

to your options. But that is not working for me and I can't see why.

I made a codepen you can find here: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWNrOg

HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="columnchart"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="drawChartColumn('zoom')">Zoom</button>
<button type="button" onclick="drawChartColumn('column1')">Column1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="drawChartColumn('column2')">Column2</button>
```

CSS

```
#columnchart {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Javascript

```
google.charts.load('43', {'packages':['bar', 'corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart(category) {
  drawChartColumn();
}

function drawChartColumn(category) {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Jaar', 'Nummer1', 'Nummer2'],
    ['2015', 238000000, 9400000000],
    ['2016', 275000000, 9700000000],
    ['2017', 339000000, 9900000000],
    ['2018', 369000000, 10100000000],
    ['2019', 3690000, 101000000],
  ]);


  if(category == 'zoom'){
    var options = {
          isStacked: true,
        animation: {
           startup:true,
           duration: 2000,
           easing: 'in',
        },
        hAxis: {viewWindow: {min:3, max:4}},
        vAxis: {viewWindow: {min:0, max:3000000}}
    };
  }
  else {
    var options = {
          isStacked: true,
        animation: {
           startup:true,
           duration: 2000,
           easing: 'in',
        },
        hAxis: {viewWindow: {min:0, max:5}}
    };
  }

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart'));


  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  var viewColumns = [0];

     switch (category) {
        case 'column2':
          viewColumns.push(1);
          viewColumns.push(2);
          break;

         case 'column1':
          viewColumns.push(1);
          break;

        default:
          viewColumns.push(1);
      }

  view.setColumns(viewColumns);
  chart.draw(view, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Google has example code but that doesn't work for me. 
I want to do 2 things:

- zoom to a value with animation like this example: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation#changing-the-view-window
- change number of columns like this example: 
  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation#adding-and-removing-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package 'bar' does not support animation. You have to use the non material corecharts for animation like the 'corechart' you already have.

Instead of 'bar' use 'corechart only

```
google.charts.load('43', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

Instead of bar.chart use visualization.ColumnChart

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));
```

And no converting is needed anymore, so use this

```
chart.draw(view, options);
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMxVNY